# Hidden url for external page load jQuery php

Tags: jquery, url, load, hidden

I load external php page using jQuery plugin with this line of code:

```
<a href="cat.php" rel="container">Tab 2</a>
```

How to hide href url (`cat.php`) for more security and not show in html source code page?

Example :

```
<a href="Block12" rel="container">Tab 2</a>
```

- Block 12 is php code to generate cat.php address
- Block 13 is php code to generate data.php address

etc...

Thanks

Comment: More security? How? This is about as secure as preventing right click via JS to keep people from accessing images or your source code.

Comment: How on earth would that amount to "security"? Anyway, you're not going to be able to do this. If the browser has the information -- and it must -- then your user does too. Move on!

Comment: If Hide Href url,user can not see this load where. this better ;)

Comment: Are you using an AJAX request to load the external content? if so, you can always just define the URL in your JS and just set '#' for the href attribute.

Comment: I change Jquery to this now : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/index.htm  this script with javascript! now how to ?

Answer (score 0):

Should do:

```
$("a[href='Block12']").attr('href', 'cat.php');
```

This will reveal the destination to the user in e.g. a status bar.

Comment: Again — this only changes the href attribute. If it makes sense to do this is a very different question.

Comment: your code this only changes the href attribute and show href and source code

Comment: It actually won't show in the source code this way, only in the dynamically generated source. Which is is available to people with e.g. Firebug. Which again would always (!) reveal the real destination of your request. Which is why this approach just doesn't make much sense to me.